# FB Timeline App Height Stuck at 800px

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-timeline

I have seen a number of other posts here regarding this which I have used to try and fix my error but it doesn't seem to be working.

Essentially I want the height to be 600px. I have tried making this settable to 600px in the app settings as well as a number of different examples of 'fixes' that I have found online however none of this seems to be working for me.

The last example I used was the following but this is not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function()
{
    FB.Canvas.setSize();
}
</script>
</head>

..
..
..

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
FB.init({
  appId: 'MYAPPID', 
  status: true, 
  cookie: true, 
  xfbml: true
});
FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(7);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your app settings, you have to set the app width to fluid, also FB.Canvas.setAutoResize now is FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow.

Answer (score 1):

You are using and old method,
`setAutoResize` have deprecated and now you have to use the `setAutoGrow`,

**FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow**
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow/

**Platform Updates: Operation Developer Love**
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/565/

Answer (score 0):

I normally use this bit of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {FB.Canvas.setSize();}
// Do things that will sometimes call sizeChangeCallback()function sizeChangeCallback()     {FB.Canvas.setSize();}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
FB.init({
appId  : "APP_ID",
status : true, // check login status
cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
xfbml  : true// parse XFBML
});

FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(7);

</script>
```

and then i set the body to the height i want and also in the app advance settings set height to fluid and it should work fine